Find match in a specified column, then find match in the matched row?
I have a dataset that looks something like this.

I'd like to make a sheet that pulls that information in this way:

So I want to write a formula that returns the date in Sheet2, row 4, of the column that matches the string "Lock" in the row whose A-column cell matches a given number.
I've tried writing the formula for Sheet1 myself, but this is as far as I can figure out:
=INDEX(Sheet2!$4:$4, 0, MATCH("Lock", <range>, 0))

That <range> is stumping me.
A "one-dimensional array" is called for. So I think I need a formula piece that searches the A-column for e.g., "103", and return that matching row in A1-notation. How do I do this?
The actual data set is much larger, spanning columns up to EF, down about 150 rows.

"Lock" isn't in column A. It appears all over the spreadsheet in other columns. It's the number value ("103") that appears in column A. I want to find "Lock" in whichever row "103" is.

can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Got it, I've just updated my question with the sample dataset. I had to reword the question a bit to match.

one-dimensional array means either:

or:

so if you want to use MATCH, searched value "Lock" needs to be anywhere in those green cells either in horizontal or vertical array. then the result will be the position of match
see if this helps:
=INDEX($4:$4, 0, MATCH("Lock", FILTER(A5:Z, A5:A=103), 0))



UPDATE 1:
=INDEX(SPLIT(TOCOL(IF(B3:L="Lock", A3:A&"×"&B2:L2, ), 1), "×"))


in your sheet:
=INDEX(SPLIT(TOCOL(IF(Sheet2!B5:Z=B1, Sheet2!A5:A&"×"&Sheet2!B4:Z4, ), 1), "×"))


UPDATE 2:
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SPLIT(TOCOL(IF(REGEXMATCH(Sheet2!B6:Z, 
 "(?i)\b"&B1&"\b"), Sheet2!A6:A&"×"&Sheet2!B4:Z4, ), 1), "×"), 2, 0)))


The updated answer isn't working on my end when pasting into B2 in my sample dataset. However, I was able to get your initial answer to work using INDEX, MATCH, and FILTER.

The plot thickens though. How do I make it so it looks for "Lock" more loosely? Not case sensitive, and allowing for only a partial match.

Final note, I've updated my example dataset further to better reflect what I'm actually working with. (Your updated answer didn't work before this edit however).

player0, you were a complete wizard with this problem awhile ago. I have to slightly update the formula to accommodate an extra dimension of reference... See the original dataset document in my question, which I've updated. Would you be able to help? Thank you!
